# Difference between `createTypedArrayList()` and `readTypedList()` in Parcel

Tags: android, serialization, deserialization, parcelable, parcel

While deserializing parcelables, I normally use the method [`createTypedArrayList (Creator<T> c)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#createTypedArrayList(android.os.Parcelable.Creator%3CT%3E)) to read parcelable array lists.

I have recently found another method  [`readTypedList (List<T> list, Creator<T> c)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#readTypedList(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20android.os.Parcelable.Creator%3CT%3E)) which seems does the exact same thing. Even the doc looks identical. Is there any difference between them apart from their implementation<sup>*</sup>?

<sup>* : The former creates new array list where the latter appends to an existing one</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Both `readTypedList()` and `createTypedArrayList()` were written as the "read" operation to go with `writeTypedList()`'s "write" operation. Since they both have to operate off of the exact same data, the differences between them are relatively small.

One obvious difference is that `readTypedList()` will "fill up" any `List` implementation you'd like (e.g. `LinkedList`, etc) whereas `createTypedArrayList()` will only ever return an `ArrayList`.

Another is that `readTypedList()` *allows* you avoid allocating more than a single `List` instance if you need to run multiple "read" operations in a row; you can pass the same `List` instance to each invocation of `readTypedList()` and then handle its contents after. `readTypedList()` will correctly overwrite existing data and grow/shrink the list as needed to exactly fit all the newly-read data. On the other hand, `createTypedArrayList()` will always return a new `ArrayList` instance.

Probably the biggest difference, though, is how they behave when you read a `null` list. If the paired "write" operation had been `dest.writeTypedList(null)`, then `createTypedArrayList()` can return a `null` value... but `readTypedList()` can only clear out the existing passed-in list, leaving you with an empty, non-null list. This makes it essentially impossible to tell whether the previously-written list was `null` or just empty, and because of this I always use `createTypedArrayList()`.

Beyond that, there aren't any differences. Both use `Creator.createFromParcel()` to actually retrieve the underlying data, and both can handle `null` elements within the list. Again, both methods are meant to be paired with `writeTypedList()`, so the potential for variation between them is quite limited.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually mentioned the first point in the question itself. The rest was helpful to me. However I think there is a better answer to the question. If the difference was as small as this, I don't think there would be two different methods.

Comment: Feel free to look at the source code. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/27f592d/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java The difference is tiny.